# Does SciKit Have A InHouse Function That Tallies The Accuracy For Each Y Solution?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have LinearSVC algorithm that predicts some data for stock. It has a 90% acc rating, but I think this might be due to the fact that some y's are far more likely than others. I want to see if there is a way to see if for each y I've defined, how accurately that y was predicted.

I haven't seen anything like this in the docs, but it just makes sense to have it.

Comment: I think [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) is what you meant by (Tallies the accuracy). Quantifying the quality of predictions is one such thing that is being done by Scikit Learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what your really want is a measure of confidence rather than actual probabilities, you can use the method `LinearSVC.decision_function()`. See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function) or the probability calibration  `CalibratedClassifierCV` using  this [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) representation implemented in SciKit to generate an accuracy matrix between the predicted and real values of your classification problem for each individual attribute. The diagonal represents the raw accuracy, which can easily be converted to a percentage accuracy.